# High Availability on Azure Service Bus using Availability Zones

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I’m looking into HA options for Azure Service Bus and I see that in preview Service Bus will support Availability Zones in some regions.  Some questions about this:

1) Is this an HA/DR solution or DR only? (Eg I won’t lose data, but I rely on azure to failover , and this may take some time).

2) Do you have an SLA with this option enabled ?

3) After this feature is GA, will we be able to enable this option on an existing namespace (in a supported region)?

Comment: Updated my answer with SLA part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this an HA/DR solution or DR only? (Eg I won’t lose data, but I rely on azure to failover , and this may take some time).

Availability Zones are solely intended for high availability (HA) and not disaster recovery (DR). Today, DR is only possible with [Geo-DR feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-geo-dr).

> After this feature is GA, will we be able to enable this option on an existing namespace (in a supported region)?

You're asking a question only a team member would be able to answer. And only if it's aligned with marketing and stars. It will support Premium tier namespaces, just as it does today. Unlikely will be added to Standard tier.

> Do you have an SLA with this option enabled ?

Geo-DR is not triggered automatically. Your system is in charge of deciding when failover is necessary and trigger it. Documentation [states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-geo-dr#setup) that "you should add some monitoring to detect if a failover is necessary.

Neither Geo-DR nor Availability Zones define a public facing SLA.